# Energy in induction furnaces

Tags: electromagnetic, induction

I have seen a question in my exam today and I don't know the real answer and need an explanation.

Energy conversion in induction furnaces:

1. heat -> electric energy -> magnetic energy
2. electric energy -> magnetic energy -> heat

I chose the 1st one but many of my friends say that it's the 2nd so we don't know. What I really think is right is that:

- Magnetic energy -> electric energy -> heat

But that sequence isn't an option so I chose the 1st as it's vice versa.!     [here is the furnace i am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXjci.png)

Comment: Please elaborate!

Comment: Thats exactly the choices in the exam 

Comment: Sure, but please elaborate on your reasoning and explain how general energy conservation laws, laws of thermodynamics, enthalpy and entropy are still valid.

Comment: Picking one that you **know** is completely reversed (for a non-reversible process) rather than an answer that is perhaps missing a step is not likely to be a successful exam-taking strategy.

Comment: Mr/Winny , what i studied says when a metal is exposed to magnetic field , eddy currents will be induced which generated heat

Comment: yes, but the heat is generated by the current, not the generating thing. So it's current->heat, not heat->electricity. That simply makes no sense.

Comment: an induction furnace is powered by electricity ... it is not powered by heat (there is nothing being burned)

Comment: So your induction furnace uses heat and produces electricity right?

Comment: @immibis If so, this guy should get the Nobel (peace) prize and enjoy financial independence for the rest of your life!

Answer (score 3):

So what is the PURPOSE of an induction ***FURNACE***? Do you think it is **using heat**, or **producing electricity**? I'll give you a hint: what does an electric FURNACE do in your house? It USES electricity to produce heat, right? So in the flow of logic of those two choices, WHY would you pick #1?

Comment: It uses  magnetic field to generate eddy currents which generate heat its not powered by electricity,  for the furnace i am talking about the induction furnace which is used for melting metals

Comment: @amrali - all yourself: when you want the furnace to run, what do you do? Do you plug in a big magnet, or do you *switch on the electricity*?

Comment: But its not a normal furnace its an induction furnace bro